# g++ timer not compatible with DPC++ Intel compiler

Tags: hpc, timing, dpc++

I've got an HPCCG file I've been trying to compile. I want to compile it with the Intel oneAPI compiler which it does successfully but the results produced suggest the timer implementation isn't working. I noticed that it works when I use the g++ compiler. This is the timer implementation source code below:

```cpp
//@HEADER
// ************************************************************************
// 
//               HPCCG: Simple Conjugate Gradient Benchmark Code
//                 Copyright (2006) Sandia Corporation
// 
// Under terms of Contract DE-AC04-94AL85000, there is a non-exclusive
// license for use of this work by or on behalf of the U.S. Government.
// 
// BSD 3-Clause License
// 
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
// 
// * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
//   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
// 
// * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
//   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
//   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
// 
// * Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its
//   contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
//   this software without specific prior written permission.
// 
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
// AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
// IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
// DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
// FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
// DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
// SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
// CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
// OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
// OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
// 
// Questions? Contact Michael A. Heroux (maherou@sandia.gov) 
// 
// ************************************************************************
//@HEADER
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Function to return time in seconds.
// If compiled with no flags, return CPU time (user and system).
// If compiled with -DWALL, returns elapsed time.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifdef USING_MPI
#include <mpi.h> // If this routine is compiled with -DUSING_MPI
                 // then include mpi.h
double mytimer(void)
{
   return(MPI_Wtime());
}


#elif defined(UseClock)

#include <time.hpp>
double mytimer(void)
{
   clock_t t1;
   static clock_t t0=0;
   static double CPS = CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   double d;

   if (t0 == 0) t0 = clock();
   t1 = clock() - t0;
   d = t1 / CPS;
   return(d);
}

#elif defined(WALL)

#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
double mytimer(void)
{
   struct timeval tp;
   static long start=0, startu;
   if (!start)
   {
      gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
      start = tp.tv_sec;
      startu = tp.tv_usec;
      return(0.0);
   }
   gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
   return( ((double) (tp.tv_sec - start)) + (tp.tv_usec-startu)/1000000.0 );
}

#elif defined(UseTimes)

#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <unistd.h>
double mytimer(void)
{
   struct tms ts;
   static double ClockTick=0.0;

   if (ClockTick == 0.0) ClockTick = (double) sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
   times(&ts);
   return( (double) ts.tms_utime / ClockTick );
}

#else

#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
double mytimer(void)
{
   struct rusage ruse;
   getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ruse);
   return( (double)(ruse.ru_utime.tv_sec+ruse.ru_utime.tv_usec / 1000000.0) );
}

#endif
```

I tried compiling this with icpx and these were my results:

```
#********** Performance Summary (times in sec) ***********: 
Time Summary: 
  Total   : 0
  DDOT    : 0
  WAXPBY  : 0
  SPARSEMV: 0
FLOPS Summary: 
  Total   : 9.536e+06
  DDOT    : 596000
  WAXPBY  : 894000
  SPARSEMV: 8.046e+06
MFLOPS Summary: 
  Total   : inf
  DDOT    : inf
  WAXPBY  : inf
  SPARSEMV: inf
```

And when I change the compiler to g++. These are my results

```
#********** Performance Summary (times in sec) ***********: 
Time Summary: 
  Total   : 0.018251
  DDOT    : 0.001142
  WAXPBY  : 0.001825
  SPARSEMV: 0.014805
FLOPS Summary: 
  Total   : 9.536e+06
  DDOT    : 596000
  WAXPBY  : 894000
  SPARSEMV: 8.046e+06
MFLOPS Summary: 
  Total   : 522.492
  DDOT    : 521.891
  WAXPBY  : 489.863
  SPARSEMV: 543.465
```

Comment: What compiler options did you use? Which compiler versions? What OS? FTR, I tried on Ubuntu 20.04 with oneAPI 2024.0 and oneAPI 2023.0 with the default Makefile options (removing the `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2` unknown option) and it just worked.

Comment: I used both dpcpp and icx compiler with an -fsycl flag. I used intel-oneapi/2022.1.2/compiler. Ubuntu Linux 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm I can reproduce the issue with oneAPI compilers until version 2023.2.3. It is fixed with version 2024.0.0. So you can either update your compiler to that version, or select another timer by using the appropriate macro in the Makefile.

NB, if you use MPI, the makefile is already set for automatically selecting the best timer (`MPI_Wtime()`).
But an excellent alternative to the default timer otherwise is obtained by adding the `-DWALL` switch to the compiler options.

```bash
$ module load intel/oneapi/2023.2.3
$ make
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o main.o main.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o generate_matrix.o generate_matrix.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o read_HPC_row.o read_HPC_row.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o compute_residual.o compute_residual.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o mytimer.o mytimer.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o dump_matlab_matrix.o dump_matlab_matrix.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o HPC_sparsemv.o HPC_sparsemv.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o HPCCG.o HPCCG.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o waxpby.o waxpby.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o ddot.o ddot.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o make_local_matrix.o make_local_matrix.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o exchange_externals.o exchange_externals.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o YAML_Element.o YAML_Element.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL       -c -o YAML_Doc.o YAML_Doc.cpp
icpx -O3 -fsycl -DWALL  main.o generate_matrix.o read_HPC_row.o compute_residual.o mytimer.o dump_matlab_matrix.o HPC_sparsemv.o HPCCG.o waxpby.o ddot.o make_local_matrix.o exchange_externals.o YAML_Element.o YAML_Doc.o -lm -o test_HPCCG
$ ./test_HPCCG 64 64 64
Initial Residual = 1654.81
Iteration = 15   Residual = 19.7523
Iteration = 30   Residual = 0.107645
Iteration = 45   Residual = 0.000229062
Iteration = 60   Residual = 4.03876e-07
Iteration = 75   Residual = 4.4229e-10
Iteration = 90   Residual = 5.59501e-13
Iteration = 105   Residual = 3.9836e-16
Iteration = 120   Residual = 1.75613e-19
Iteration = 135   Residual = 5.38692e-22
Iteration = 149   Residual = 7.18448e-25
Mini-Application Name: hpccg
Mini-Application Version: 1.0
Parallelism: 
  MPI not enabled: 
  OpenMP not enabled: 
Dimensions: 
  nx: 64
  ny: 64
  nz: 64
Number of iterations: 149
Final residual: 7.18448e-25
#********** Performance Summary (times in sec) ***********: 
Time Summary: 
  Total   : 0.67078
  DDOT    : 0.024968
  WAXPBY  : 0.066434
  SPARSEMV: 0.579066
FLOPS Summary: 
  Total   : 2.49981e+09
  DDOT    : 1.56238e+08
  WAXPBY  : 2.34357e+08
  SPARSEMV: 2.10921e+09
MFLOPS Summary: 
  Total   : 3726.71
  DDOT    : 6257.52
  WAXPBY  : 3527.66
  SPARSEMV: 3642.44
```